# Updating AWS API Gateway Body Mapping Templates at API level with JavaScript SDK

Tags: aws-api-gateway

What is the right JavaScript API to update the body mapping templates at the API level?

`updateIntegrationResponse` cannot do it at this level.

Answer (score 0):

We end up using the api below. A bit of tricky part is you need to replace the slash with ~1 to make it work.

```
        const params = {
            responseType: response.type.toString(), /* required */
            restApiId: apiId, /* required */
            patchOperations:[{
                op: 'add',
                path: '/responseTemplates/'+ response.bodyMappingTemplate.contentType.replace("/", "~1"),
                value: response.bodyMappingTemplate.content
              }
            ]
        };
        this.apiGatewaySDK.updateGatewayResponse(params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            else {
                this.serverless.cli.log('API Gateway Configuring: Body mapping templates are set correctly');
                resolve('Body Mapping Templates set successfully:', response.type);
            }
        });
```